# Ubuntu 18.04 -- sound output or input not being detected. Drivers are working

Tags: sound, pulseaudio

I get a dummy output any time I try to run the sound on Ubuntu 18.04. The drivers are working but when I do `pacmd list-cards`, I get

`index: 0
    name: <alsa_card.pci-0000_01_00.1>
    driver: <module-alsa-card.c>
    owner module: 7
    properties:
        alsa.card = "1"
        alsa.card_name = "HDA NVidia"
        alsa.long_card_name = "HDA NVidia at 0xad080000 irq 17"
        alsa.driver_name = "snd_hda_intel"
        device.bus_path = "pci-0000:01:00.1"
        sysfs.path = "/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1"
        device.bus = "pci"
        device.vendor.id = "10de"
        device.vendor.name = "NVIDIA Corporation"
        device.product.id = "10f0"
        device.product.name = "GP104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        device.string = "1"
        device.description = "GP104 High Definition Audio Controller"
        module-udev-detect.discovered = "1"
        device.icon_name = "audio-card-pci"
    profiles:
        output:hdmi-stereo: Digital Stereo (HDMI) Output (priority 5400, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI) Output (priority 300, available: no)
        output:hdmi-stereo-extra1: Digital Stereo (HDMI 2) Output (priority 5200, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround-extra1: Digital Surround 5.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        output:hdmi-surround71-extra1: Digital Surround 7.1 (HDMI 2) Output (priority 100, available: no)
        off: Off (priority 0, available: unknown)
    active profile: <off>
    ports:
        hdmi-output-0: HDMI / DisplayPort (priority 5900, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"
        hdmi-output-1: HDMI / DisplayPort 2 (priority 5800, latency offset 0 usec, available: no)
            properties:
                device.icon_name = "video-display"`

For some reason, its not detecting the analog input or output. Pulseaudio seems to be running okay. Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have an HDMI cable? If so, plug it in and unplug it to see if that refreshes your devices. If you have headphones, do the same with the headphone jack. This will sometimes solve the issue.